# Is there anyway to (easily) convert a regular LCD monitor into a touchscreen monitor?

Tags: display, touchscreen

I've seen some kind of overlay thing you can get for CRT monitors to make them touchscreen(I saw this at a movie theater) and I was completely amazed. Well, I want to do this to my LCD monitor. Where can I get one of these devices? Multitouch is a plus, as is Linux support, though neither are absolutely required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have no experience in this but the following [article from eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_6698669_convert-lcd-touch-screen.html) seems promising:

> Using a touch screen with a computer
>   allows you to do some things you
>   wouldn't be able to do with just a
>   mouse and keyboard. You can interact
>   with the computer in a more natural
>   way. You can also make sketches or
>   take quick notes. Converting a liquid
>   crystal display (LCD) to a touch
>   screen **can be done by installing one
>   of many kits** available. These kits
>   contain a clear screen overlay to put
>   over the monitor, a screen controller
>   and universal serial bus (USB) or
>   other cable type that plugs into your
>   computer. The touch screen overlay is
>   the same size of the computer monitor
>   and is installed over the monitor in
>   the monitor case. This is a fairly
>   simple upgrade that most people can
>   perform.
>
> Things You'll Need:
>
> - LCD touch screen conversion kit
> - Microfiber cloth

The instructions are explained here: [How to Convert an LCD to a Touch Screen](http://www.ehow.com/how_6698669_convert-lcd-touch-screen.html#ixzz191DCLuz5)

You can google for those touch add-on kits. I came across [this](http://www.magictouch.com/addon.html), for example.

Comment: A tad bit expensive sadly :(